# Xcode Loop into Array

Tags: ios, xcode

For loop error;
i want to repeat [Demophoto] line 
can someone help me please

sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/177kvpp72pfh8ul/myTest.zip?dl=0

```
allPhoto = [NSMutableArray array];
[allPhoto addObject:@"http://www.ed.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.129149!/fileManager/Mohamad-Hanif-Awang-Senik_2ndLRG.jpg"];
[allPhoto addObject:@"http://thehandmadephotograph.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/smithsonian-photo-contest-winner-2012-crop.jpg__800x600_q85_crop.jpg"];
[allPhoto addObject:@"https://cdn.tutsplus.com/photo/uploads/legacy/352_greatphototuts/greatPhotoTuts-68.jpg"];



  [self setPhotos:@[

    for(int i=0; i < [allPhoto count]; i++){
        [DEMOPhoto photoWithProperties: @{@"imageFile": @"1.jpg" }],
    }

 ]];
```

Comment: What you really want as output?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Why did you wrote loop inside the function argument ?

Comment: i want to just for loop inside Self setPhotos:@

Comment: Please paste your log with the error

Comment: i am uploading sample project now

Comment: this is link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/177kvpp72pfh8ul/myTest.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=0; i < [allPhoto count]; i++){
    [tempArray addObject:[DEMOPhoto photoWithProperties: @{@"imageFile": @"1.jpg" }]];
}
[self setPhotos:tempArray];
```